# Riverpod - Create service with async dependency better/elegant way

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I've writen some code that provides a `ApiService` to a `StateNotifier`. The `ApiService` has a dependency on a `authenticatorclient` - The auth client has to be created asynchronously as it uses sharedprefs to get a token.

Im just trying to figure out if theirs a more elegant way to how I've written this. Basically when the service apiService is injected into the StateNotifier it could be nullable... That to me is a bit of a code smell.

So in brief this is what im doing...
use a `FutureProvider` to Instantiate the `RestClient`with a `Dio`

```
authenticatorClient = FutureProvider<RestClient>((ref) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final dio = Dio();
  ...
  return RestClient(dio);
}
```

And then I watch that and use a MaybeWhen to return the service

```
final clientCreatorWatchProvider = Provider<ApiService?>((ref) => ref
    .watch(authenticatorClient)
    .whenData((value) => ApiService(value))
    .maybeWhen(
      data: (service) => service,
      orElse: () => null,
    ));
```

So the bit I dont like is the orElse returning null

And then my `StateNotifier` is watching...

```
final AppState = StateNotifierProvider<AppNotifier, String>(
    (ref) => AppNotifier(ref.watch(clientCreatorWatchProvider)));

class AppNotifier extends StateNotifier<String> {
  final ApiService? apiService;

  AppNotifier(this.apiService) : super("loading") {
    init();
  }
...
}
```

Any thoughts on the above approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to initialize `SharedPreferences` outside of a provider. You can then use `ProviderScope` to override a synchronous provider, eliminating the need to work with `AsyncValue`.

When you initialize your app, do the following:

```dart
final sharedPreferences = Provider<SharedPreferences>((_) => throw UnimplementedError());

Future<void> main() async {
  final sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        sharedPreferences.overrideWithValue(sharedPrefs),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now you could write your providers like so:

```dart
final authenticatorClient = Provider<RestClient>((ref) {
  final prefs = ref.watch(sharedPreferences);
  final dio = Dio();
  ...
  return RestClient(dio);
}

final clientCreatorWatchProvider = Provider<ApiService>((ref) {
  final authClient = ref.watch(authenticatorClient);
  return ApiService(authClient);
});
```

Comment: Does this really work? See https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/575 about providers watching other providers and not getting the overridden value.

Comment: @wujek For this case, yes it does. I avoid using ProviderScope outside of the root app, like in this example, so I can't speak to other cases.

Comment: This is a better solution than most of the answers on SO. 
Wish I could +1 it more.